# Vulnerabilities scan from Google cloud

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm planing to run vulnerabilities scan using Kali linux from gcloud instance to our servers located on different providers, how should I notify Google team to don't get banned?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not directly related to programming, but cloud security.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by reading [Security and Compliance](https://cloud.google.com/security/).

> Penetration Testing
>
> If you plan to evaluate the security of your Cloud Platform
>   infrastructure with penetration testing, you are not required to
>   contact us to begin testing. You will have to abide by the Cloud
>   Platform Acceptable Use Policy and the Terms of Service and ensure
>   that your tests only affect your projects (and not other customers’
>   applications). If a vulnerability is found, please report it via the
>   Vulnerability Reward Program.

However, this applies to services hosted on Google cloud itself.
If you plan to test services on other cloud providers, you should read their security guidelines first as well.